# Why does bootstrap use html4 in its examples?

Tags: html

I've noticed that very few web front-end divs actually use new semantic markup of html5. Is there a particular reason for that, other than it is easier?

Boostrap is glaring example of not caring about semantic web. Examples are just divs inside divs.

Comment: If it's not broke etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Semantics are great. HTML5 is great. And everyone should learn as much about it as they can. But not everyone has. Bootstrap doesn't aim to be an arbiter of HTML5, they want to make a great framework for all developers, even the ones still using HTML4.

So they show us the way that works for everyone. But there's nothing stopping you from using it's classes with html5 semantic tags.